# Finding the best site for posting a question

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation

Many times I have a question that is more about the technology underlying architectural features than just a pure "programming language" question. So what I currently do is a search for something like "WebDav server" and get hits for Super User, Stack Overflow, etc.

What I would like instead of a list is a histogram, that would point me to where the most discussions of some network and server technologies take place.

Then I would focus my question for that particular site and its rules.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a forum. We are a Q&A site. Feel free to call the sites "sites"... there was a Meta question about it at some point... regardless, please don't think of the sites as forums. Doing so leads to confusion of our purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a really good idea every time. If I want to know which kind of apple the one on the left [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAUaw.png) is, and search for 'apple', I'd probably end up at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Glorfindel But determining whether [cooking.se] or [gardening.se] would be better to ask would be fun.

Comment: There is an explanation of the different IT Stack Exchange sites [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in).

Comment: I will make it a more concrete question. I have no idea whether to post to stack overflow, super-user, or server-fault. Some of my questions could fall into any of  them. So for a particular subject area, which have overlaps, how would one find the correct site?

Comment: @Dr.YSG see S.L. Barth's link, that is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: and all meta sites are open for site-recommendations so you can ask there if that specific question would be on topic on the main site

Comment: @Glorfindel I did look there, it does not cover super-user, server-fault, and then are some that overlap hardware and software. Besides this is something that is a dynamic re-balancing of categories, so you don't want to point people to a static document, you want somethign that dynamically bin's your question to the correct forum. Hence the request for a historgram.

Comment: Oh, you're right, those aren't covered. I got confused with another canonical Q&A (while writing a SEDE query to produce your histogram).

Comment: @rene Provided you have 5 rep...

Comment: @Catija for this OP that is no problem, but you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I'm not sure a histogram is the right tool to use for [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

That said, you can produce some kind of a histogram with this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/586961/number-of-hits-for-a-certain-query-on-all-stack-exchange-sites?query=apple). These are the results for 'apple':

[image]

I had to limit the posts being searched in to the last two months, because otherwise the query times out. For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
declare @query nvarchar(200) = ##query:string##

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #results (site nvarchar(250), numberofhits int);

open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) + ';
    insert into #results 
    select ''' + QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) + ''', count(*)
      from posts
      where creationdate >= ''2016-10-01''
        and body LIKE ''%' + CAST(@query AS nvarchar) + '%'';'
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select * from #results
  where numberofhits > 0
  order by numberofhits desc;
```

Note that SEDE is updated once every week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: @Glofindel this is fantastic. Great work.

Comment: @Dr.YSG you're welcome. SEDE is a mighty tool for a lot of purposes.

Comment: You can maybe filter out meta sites but the posts table on SO is killing the query as you'll need a full table scan.

Comment: @rene yeah, I thought that was the main problem so I didn't bother to skip the Meta sites.